# Proving a function bounded between integrable functions is integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-writing, riemann-integration

Let $I=[a,b]$, $f,g,h$ bounded functions in $I$ with real values. Suppose $f(x)\leq g(x)\leq h(x)$ $\forall x\in R$. Prove that if $f$ and $h$ are integrable in $I$ and if $\int_a^b f =\int_a^b h$ then $g$ is also integrable in $I$ and $\int_a^b g =\int_a^b f$.

My attempt:
Given that f and g are integrable then we have that $L(f)=U(f)$ and $L(h)=U(h)$ and since the integrals of $f$ and $g$ in $I$ are equal then I guess that $L(f)=L(h)$ and $U(f)=U(h)$ ?

I think that f and h share the same upper and lower integral, and I can see the solution to this problem intuitively, I was thinking there must be a way to get to $L(g)=U(g)$ and that it's integral is equal to the integral of f using the fact that g is bounded in between f and h.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $f^+=\max\{f,0\}$ and $f^-=\max\{-f,0\}$. A function is integrable if and only if the positive part $f^+$ and the negative part $f^-$, which are both nonnegative, are integrable meaning
$$0\leq\int f^+ dx<\infty  \text{ and } 0\leq\int f^- dx<\infty.$$

Now, check that by hypothesis, $g\leq h$ implies $g^+\leq h^+$ and so if $\int h^+ dx<\infty$, then $\int g^+ dx<\infty$ by comparison theorem. In the same way, $f\leq g$ implies $g^-\leq f^-$ and integrability of $f^-$ implies that of $g^-$.  So $g$ is integrable.

Now that the integrability is proved, you just take the integral of all sides and if the first integral equals the third integral, the second integral also must be equal to the other two (circle inequalities in algebra: $a\leq b\leq a$ implies $a=b$)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Excellent proof, but I think I can't use it because it has theorems that aren't in my course, I can only use Riemann's criterion for integrability and some basic properties of the integral.